# How to properly structure lists with many sub-levels

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, menu

I have a large navigation menu made using li and ul tags. The problem I have is that if I try to style individual items, it becomes very challenging because each li tag has multiple ul and li elements within it and therefore the style gets applied to everything within it. For example, I'm trying to highlight the first list item "SharePoint Demo Website" but that first item contains all the other items, it's an expandable/collapsible menu).

HTML:

```
<ul id="expList" class="list">
    <li title="Sharepoint Demo Website" value="https://demo.ca" class="collapsed expanded active">Sharepoint Demo Website
        <ul style="display: block;">
            <li title="Academic" value="https://demo.ca/academic" class="collapsed">Academic
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li title="Board Meetings" value="https://demo.ca/academic/bm">Board Meetings</li>
                    <li title="Committee" value="https://demo.ca/academic/cmtte">Committee</li>
                    <li title="Document Management" value="https://demo.ca/academic/dm">Document Management</li>
                    <li title="Project Management" value="https://demo.ca/academic/pm">Project Management</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li title="Archive" value="https://demo.ca/archive">Archive</li>
            <li title="Associations" value="https://demo.ca/associations" class="collapsed">Associations
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li title="Board Meetings" value="https://demo.ca/associations/bm">Board Meetings</li>
                    <li title="Document Management" value="https://demo.ca/associations/dm">Document Management</li>
                    <li title="Project Management" value="https://demo.ca/associations/pm">Project Management</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li title="Developer" value="https://demo.ca/cdn">Developer</li>
            <li title="Person test" value="https://demo.ca/cf_test">Person test</li>
            <li title="Charity" value="https://demo.ca/charity" class="collapsed">Charity
                <ul style="display: none;">
                    <li title="Board of Directors" value="https://demo.ca/charity/bod" class="collapsed">Board of Directors
                        <ul style="display: none;"><li title="Board Documents" value="https://demo.ca/charity/bod/boarddocs">Board Documents</li>
                            <li title="Meeting Materials" value="https://demo.ca/charity/bod/mtgmaterial">Meeting Materials</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li title="demo" value="https://demo.ca/clite" class="collapsed">demo
                <ul style="display: none;"><li title="administrator" value="https://demo.ca/clite/admin">administrator
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li title="Company" value="https://demo.ca/company" class="collapsed">Company
            <ul style="display: none;"><li title="Finance" value="https://demo.ca/company/finance">Finance</li>
                <li title="Human Resources" value="https://demo.ca/company/hr" class="collapsed">Human Resources

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    #expList ul li:hover{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is the code that creates the list:

```
function traverseMap(obj, element) {
      for (var key in obj) {
          var item = obj[key];

          var li = $('<li>', {
                  text: item.title,
                  title: item.title,
                  value: item.url
              }).appendTo(element);

          if (!$.isEmptyObject(item.children)) {
              var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo(li);
              traverseMap(item.children, ul);
          }
      }
  }
  traverseMap(map, $('#expList'));
}
```

Comment: i highly recommend using class names instead of trying to rely on html structure and targeting via '>'. You will save yourself lots of time down the road with maintenance and debugging.

Comment: I'm not opposed to that, I might have to change the way the lists are generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` to affect only immediate children, like this:

```
#expList ul > li:hover{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

or this:

```
#expList > ul > li:hover{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

or use the `:first-child` pseudo selector for just the first child:

```
#expList ul li:first-child:hover
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

depending on what you want. You could also use class names.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough. I need to style each li item on hover. No only the first one. So basically whatever individual item is hovered should be styled. I think ur solution will only work on the first item.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have right now it won't work, because the whole node will get highlighted, what you need to do is to give an extra mark up to the text you wanna highlight, for example :

```
<li title="Academic" value="https://demo.ca/academic" class="collapsed">
<span>Academic</span>
     <ul style="display: none;">
          <li title="Board Meetings" value="https://demo.ca/academic/bm">Board Meetings</li>
          <li title="Committee" value="https://demo.ca/academic/cmtte">Committee</li>
          <li title="Document Management" value="https://demo.ca/academic/dm">Document Management</li>
          <li title="Project Management" value="https://demo.ca/academic/pm">Project Management</li>
      </ul>
 </li>
```

then :

```
#expList ul > li:hover > span{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that `<li title="Sharepoint Demo Website" value="https://demo.ca" class="collapsed expanded active">` contains a text node and children elements, a rule that styles the `li` will also apply to its children.

If you want to style the text node ("Sharepoint Demo Website") independently you will have to wrap it in an element which you can target specifically.

```
<ul id="expList" class="list">
  <li title="Sharepoint Demo Website" value="https://demo.ca" class="collapsed expanded active">
    <span>Sharepoint Demo Website</span>
    <ul style="display: block;">
      <li title="Academic" value="https://demo.ca/academic" class="collapsed">Academic
        <ul style="display: none;">
```

You could now apply a rule to the text node via the `span`

```
#expList li > span {
  background-color:#fee;
}
```

See [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3QgX/).

Comment: Hmm so instead of targeting the list item, I target the span, seems like a good idea, I'll try to modify the Javascript to create a span around the text item